# Using the up/down arrow buttons, can I post several sentences to a GTK window?

Tags: c, linux

A friend helped me create two small boxes around the *up-arrow* and *down-arrow* icons.  I have several--let's say 64--sentences in `/usr/share/voices` that I need to display in the window with arrows. My question is how to use

```
FILE *infile = fopen (filename, "r");
```

to open, read, and write the 64 sentences to the window?  How would I use the arrow code to go from text.`1` to text.`65`?

Here is more of the code surrounding `fopen();`

```
GetTextBuffer *buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (view));
gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_offset (buffer, &iter, 0);

filename = g_build_filename ("usr/share/voice", ifbuf, NULL);
infile = fopen (filename, "r");
if (infile)
{
    while (1)
      {
         nchars = fread (file_buff, 1, MAXCHAT, infile);
         gtk_text_buffer_insert (buffer, &iter, file_buff, nchars);
         if (nchars < MAXCHAT)
            break;
      }
    fclose (infile);
 }
```

Sorry this is so complicated. In `ifbuf` are the commands printed into `sprintf()` and have  roughly `espeak | aplay`. The entire program is for the Accessibility bunch and meant to help the speech-impaired. The speech-impaired texts are written into `/usr/share/voice` and then read by the computer for the other(s) to hear. The arrows track the sentences to be printing or spoken on the **GTK+** table in case someone wants it re-read.

Hope  that someone can help me. I'm using **Ubuntu** and just finished upgrading to **14.04**.

Comment: Is this the only task the program will accomplish?  If so, I might consider using something like Python and PyGTK, particularly if you are not that familiar with C.  (I'm not saying that using C is wrong, by any stretch.)

Comment: To start with I suggest you learn more about the C [standard I/O functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io), for example [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). Then I suggest you learn the difference between relative paths (like `usr/share/voice`) and absolute paths (like `/usr/share/voice`). Then you should probably learn about such basic concepts as [linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). And the very last you should worry about GTK+ and how to get it to work with the previous things you learned.

Comment: the "usr/share/voice" was a typo.  I've been using C since 1978 and am *reasonably* good.  typing:: different story.

Comment: FWIW:  {I forgot this}: the quoted string was this:   

filename = g_build_filename (vhome, ifbuf, NULL);

"vhome" was originally in my home (/home/kline) directories.  Currently,
when I click on the arrows, I
print one of two strings.  I need to know how to have GTK move the 64 strings
into the GTK window *and* grab the strings, move them up/down, and have
espeak|aplay  give them voice.  One of my friends is nearly blind.